# Change 'Submit' button and helper text in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm looking for a way to use a script to change the text of a 'Submit' button in Google Form, as well as the helper text.

Since there is no way to select the output language of the form (it's auto generated base on browser settings) I would like to know if there is a way to create a script that will change the text of the said button as well as the text helper such as 'Your Answer' in the textboxes.

I would like to change it so it becomes bilingual "Envoyer / Submit".

The `http://...../viewform?hl=fr` trick is NOT working and therefor I cannot offer my user a choice of language.

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation of [Language Service in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/)?

Comment: Yes I have but couldn't find anything relevant.